# changing dll location in setup project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I want to change the location of the Dll libraries needed for a wpf project, this is really what I've done, but while installing the app, it gives me an error that some components are not found and it exits!

Comment: If you are using refresh file to indicate the dll location?

Comment: What sort of installer do you use? I guess you need to ensure that they are present at desired location after installation.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to make the referenced DLLs local - means copy them locally when you build them: just set the "Copy Local" property true at the properties toolbox after you select the DLL(s).